# Extracting events sequences in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, events, logstash, sequence, elk

I have events collecting in ELK. I need to extract sequences of event and analyse them. To count of sequences, view events parameters statistics in sequence etc.

Let's see an example.

There are 3 types of event: event_of_type_1, event_of_type_2, event_of_type_3. Also the events of these types have different parameters.

I have all logged events:

1. **event_of_type_1** happened in 12:00
2. **event_of_type_2** happened in 12:05
3. **event_of_type_1** happened in 12:10
4. **event_of_type_3** happened in 12:15
5. **event_of_type_2** happened in 12:20
6. **event_of_type_1** happened in 12:25
7. **event_of_type_2** happened in 12:30

My task is extracting all sequences, where the first event is event_type_1 and the next event is event_type_2. Also there is a condition between parameters values of first and second events of sequence. In the result sequences some of 1st event parameters must be equal to sone of 2nd event parameters.

So, the result I need is the next lines of start log:

1. **event_of_type_1** happened in 12:00
2. **event_of_type_2** happened in 12:05

and

6. **event_of_type_1** happened in 12:25
7. **event_of_type_2** happened in 12:30

Where the condition for parameters is met in both sequences.

**Do you know the way how can I do it in ELK?**
I think that I can't use common "Discovery" tool, cause I don't know hot to set the term that event_of_type_1 must be 1st and event_of_type_2 must be the 2nd and also parameters values term. It seems that I just can filter the whole list of event and leave event_of_type_1 and event_of_type_1 without these terms.

Comment: Can you share sample documents?

Comment: Have you looked into [EQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eql.html) from elastic ?

Comment: @MusabDogan, sorry, I can't

Comment: @Paulo, just started to look. Can you suggest, what chapter should me see the first?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eql.html#eql-search-sequence

Comment: Sounds like the right place. If you need more help I suggest you provide sample documents as @MusabDogan asked

Comment: @Paulo, thank you for proposal!

Maybe you know, can I visualize data after getting it by eql queries?
I cat get JSON with data, but it will be too hard to analyse that in such presentation. Is there the way to use Kibana for result data?